# Java generic method call

Tags: java, generics

Consider the following code:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>> collection = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>> outCollecttion = <String, Integer, HashMap<String, Integer>, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>>>doSomeWork(collection);
    }

    public static <V extends Object, U extends Object, K extends Map<V, U>, J extends Collection<K>> Collection<K> doSomeWork(J collection) {
        Collection<K> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (K element : collection) {
            result.add(element); //here is supposed other code, this is just example
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

I want to do some work on a generic collection that contains map of some generic types. I know that Java has hard time figuring complex generic expressions, so I put explicit types before method call:

```
<String, Integer, HashMap<String, Integer>, ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, String>>>doSomeWork(collection)
```

But compiler will not compile that. I do understand that it might have something to do with the fact that I'm trying to use generic type in generic type, but I don't know how to write this method without using casts and than deprecating warnings (I usually compile with -Xlint:unchecked flag).

Comment: Maybe you accidentally switched Integer and String in `ArrayList<Hashmap<...>>`?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, but it still no use. Edited code in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when you want to explicitly provide the type arguments, you have to call the method from its class:

```
... = MainClass.<String, Integer, HashMap<String, Integer>, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>>>doSomeWork(collection);
```

Second, your method returns `Collection<K>`, but the variable is declared `ArrayList<...>`. The following works for me:

```
Collection<HashMap<String, Integer>> outCollecttion = ...
```

Comment: That is definitely helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use generics in assignment.

```
Collection<HashMap<String, Integer>> outCollecttion = doSomeWork(collection);
```

Comment: Have you tried to compile it? Because it will not. `Error:(12, 72) java: incompatible types; no instance(s) of type variable(s) V,U,K exist so that java.util.Collection<K> conforms to java.util.ArrayList<java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer>>
  required: java.util.ArrayList<java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer>>
  found:    <V,U,K>java.util.Collection<K>`